# How to load SR parser file in hdfs in the mapper?

Tags: java, hadoop, stanford-nlp

I am trying to use the CoreNLP project in a mapreduce program to find the sentiment of a large number of text stored in `hbase` tables. I am using the SR parser for parsing. The model file is stored in hdfs at `/user/root/englishSR.ser.gz`. I  have added the below line in the mapreduce application code

```
 job.addCacheFile(new URI("/user/root/englishSR.ser.gz#model"));
```

Now in the mapper

```
 props.setProperty("parse.model", "./model");
```

I am getting `edu.stanford.nlp.io.RuntimeIOException: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: invalid stream header`. 
The `pom.xml` file contains

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>edu.stanford.nlp</groupId>
        <artifactId>stanford-corenlp</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>edu.stanford.nlp</groupId>
    <artifactId>stanford-corenlp</artifactId>
    <version>3.4.1</version>
    <classifier>models</classifier>
</dependency>
```

I have tried adding the file to `resources` and adding to the `maven` with all resulting in `GC overhead limit exceeded` or Java Heap issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know hadoop well, but I suspect that you're confusing CoreNLP about the compression of the SR parser model.

First try this without using Hadoop:

```
java -mx4g edu.stanford.nlp.parser.shiftreduce.ShiftReduceParser -serializedPath /user/root/englishSR.ser.gz
```

See if that loads the parser fine. If so, it should print something like the below and exit (otherwise, it will throw an exception...).

```
Loading parser from serialized file edu/stanford/nlp/models/srparser/englishSR.ser.gz ... done [10.4 sec].
```

If that loads a parser fine, then there is nothing wrong with the model file. I think the problem is then that CoreNLP simply uses whether a file or resource name ends in ".gz" to decide whether it is gzipped, and so it wrongly interprets the line:

```
props.setProperty("parse.model", "./model");
```

as saying to load a not-gzipped model.  So I would hope that one or other of the below would work:

```
cd /user/root ; gunzip englishSR.ser.gz

job.addCacheFile(new URI("/user/root/englishSR.ser#model"));

props.setProperty("parse.model", "./model");
```

Or:

```
job.addCacheFile(new URI("/user/root/englishSR.ser#model.gz"));

props.setProperty("parse.model", "./model.gz");
```

Comment: I have changed the code as you have suggested. I think the loading of parser file is successful. The `invalid stream header` error no longer appears. But again I am getting `GC overhead limit exceeded` and `Java Heap space` issues. As mentioned in the question I have already tried adding the parser file in `resources`, `maven` and  now in `hdfs`. Each of them failed with the same error. I have tried increasing the memory by setting `mapreduce.map.memory.mb` to `4096` and `mapred.child.java.opts` to `-Xmx4096m`.

Comment: The error messages definitely mean that the mappers aren't getting enough memory, but I think you'll need to find more of an Hadoop expert to say how to fix that. But, just checking, I hope your list of annotators doesn't include "coref", since the (now default) statistical coref can easily require more than 4GB.

Comment: No the annotators list does not include `coref`.